# Cannot attach debugger to Azure Web Service chatbot app

Tags: visual-studio, azure, remote-debugging, botframework

I follow [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/09/22/remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app/) but I keep getting this error, described in the article. Also I cannot find the IP of the KUDU? Where should I look at?

This part specifically I don't understand:

> "Without going into much detail, what you have to do is get the IP address of your KUDU console, which I describe here and use that IP address for the *.azurewebsites.net hostname you are remote debugging by adding the IP HOSTNAME combination to the HOSTS file."

What should I type in here:

[image: 1]

This is the error VS pops up:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named ‘***’.  The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.

Also I am using VS 2017 and cannot see an option for it in Azure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kudo can be opened by navigating to https://[YourAppServiceName].scm.azurewebsites.net  or by right clicking on your app in Visual Studio's Cloud Explorer window and choosing "Open in Kudo".

[image]

To find the ip: https://[YourAppServiceName].scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml

However, once you have clicked "Attach Debugger" in the cloud explorer, you should be able to drop down the Qualifier (re-named Connection Target in vs2017) combo box, and select the correct option ([YourBotName].azurewebsites.net:4022 in my case):

Comment: I see multiple sections when I navigate to Env.cshtml page. Can you please help in where exactly I can get IP address.